# Laravel package installed with Composer: dependencies missing, service provider not found

Tags: php, laravel, git, gitlab, composer-php

I installed a package from a private GitLab repository using Composer. The package is forked from `djoudi/Laravel-H5P` on GitHub. By *installed* I mean that there's now a new directory `vendor/mycompany/laravel-h5p` containing the files.

When I install the original package from GitHub with `composer require djoudi/laravel-h5p`, everything is fine. But using the package from GitLab, two things don't work:

- The package contains a `composer.json`. The dependencies specified in this file aren't installed.
- I'd usually do `php artisan vendor:publish` and select the package to publish migration files, views etc. But in my case the package is not listed at all.

I've got no idea how to address the first problem. I tried to add `Djoudi\LaravelH5p\LaravelH5pServiceProvider::class` to the providers array in `config.app.php` and `Djoudi\\LaravelH5p\\": "src/LaravelH5p"` to the `autoload > psr-4` key in `composer.json` to address the second problem. This didn't work.

How can I make the package from GitLab work?

Comment: Take a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: Thanks, the code in the first code sample in that section did the trick (using the appropriate URL and `"djoudi/laravel-h5p": "dev-master"`).